# OpenCV: Why is one trackbar shorter than others?

Tags: python, opencv

I have encountered a strange issue and would like someone to explain it to me, so I can avoid it in the future. When I place multiple trackbars (6 in my case) the last trackbar is much shorter. Here is the base code:

```py
import cv2

def nothing(arguments):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('TrackBars')
cv2.resizeWindow('TrackBars', 500, 300)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 1', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 2', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 3', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 4', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 5', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 6', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have noticed that making the window larger solves the problem:

```py
cv2.resizeWindow('TrackBars', 500, 320)
```

Even though there is a lot of space below, I thought that maybe the window crops the trackbar making it behave strange. However, while preparing the code to post here, I discovered that having 2 or 3 trackbars works fine even when one is cropped by the window. Only when there is 4 or more this behavior occurs.

```py
import cv2

def nothing(arguments):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('TrackBars')
cv2.resizeWindow('TrackBars', 500, 60)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 1', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider 2', 'TrackBars', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

What is happening here? Why is one of the trackbars shorter but only when there is many of them?

---

Additional infomation:

- **OpenCV**: 4.6.0.66
- **OS**: Windows 10
- **HighGUI backend**: WinAPI

Comment: Can you please share your opencv version?

Comment: opencv-python 4.6.0.66

Comment: What OS and what HighGUI backend? | I can reproduce the issue on Windows, with multiple versions of OpenCV going at least as far back as 3.3.

Comment: I am using Win10. I have no idea what HighGUI even is so whatever is default, it's probably that.

Comment: Thanks. JFYI HIghGUI (short for high-level GUI) is the name of the [OpenCV module](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) that implements the functions you're using here. The Windows builds by default use WinAPI, so that's gonna be your case. | Please, [edit] your question and add those details there.

Comment: And this is probably the least weird thing it can do -- make the window 800x200 and I get both 5 and 6 short and on the same row. Create 500x200 with flag `WINDOW_NORMAL`, stretch the window using the mouse and a blank button appears on the toolbar at some widths.

Comment: Oh man, you tempted me into opening a can of worms :D There's a number of bugs (already filed 2 issues, and at least 2 more i'm aware of now, but haven't figured out yet fully). For now, maybe build your own GUI with tkinter, it's fairly simple.

Comment: And found it: https://i.imgur.com/LFsLykV.png

Comment: Sorry for tempting you :D I was thinking of making a separate GUI but I don't even really need this. This code was part of a shot YT intro course on OpenCV. What shocked me is that it has over 44k views and nobody seemed to be bothered byt that short trackbar :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in OpenCV that seems to have been lingering there for a while. After a few hours of digging (and uncovering few other issues in the code along the way), I think I've nabbed it and filed a [bug report](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22767) with proposed resolution. I'll be making a pull request in the near future, and hopefully this can be resolved in the 4.7.0 release.

To summarize the problem: trackbar controls are added to a toolbar control, which grows vertically as more controls are added. Since main window size is fixed at the point when the controls are being created, the remaining "client area" not taken up by the toolbar progressively shrinks, until there is no space left (so its size becomes 0).

The bug is that in order to set the width of the trackbar  controls, the width of that remaining "client area" is used. Once that "client area" shrinks to nothing, the size of it becomes 0, and Windows uses some other value as default width for the trackbar.

Using the width of the toolbar (which is always available) solves the problem.

With that fix applied, I can get the following:

[image]

---

Update: Many of the fixes will also be applied to the 3.4 branch.